# Why dns_get_record not working for some domains?

Tags: php, dns, dns-get-record

I use `dns_get_record` and `getmxrr` to get domain data mx and ns

But for some domains I can't get data, for example domain `tecmilenio.mx`
`dns_get_record('tecmilenio.mx', DNS_NS)` return false with warning `dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occurred.`

I checked console command `nslookup -type=mx tecmilenio.mx` and it nothing find, and show error

> Server:       127.0.1.1
>
> Address:  127.0.1.1#53
>
> ** server can't find tecmilenio.mx: SERVFAIL

Why it appears for some domains and how to solve it?

Comment: This specific domain name is badly configured and is in a lame delegation case, see http://dnsviz.net/d/tecmilenio.mx/dnssec/

Answer (score 0):

It isn't compulsory for a domain to have an MX record. In the absence of an MX record, email senders will attempt delivery to the address record - e.g. example.com.

This is based on RFC 5321 sec. 5, which states :

SMTP clients must look up an MX record;
If (and only if) no MX record for the domain is present, treat the domain as if it had an MX record with the given domain as the target hostname and a preference value of 0
Perform A or AAAA lookups as required to determine the IP address of the target hostname

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record

Comment: This is true, but then the nameserver should reply NXDOMAIN for the query, and not SERVFAIL.